# Login page issue (flask ,python)

Tags: python, flask

I'm pretty much new to Python and Flask and trying to create website with user registration and user login.

I'm able to create users using Registration page but i'm unable to login using same user credential which were used during user registration.

Below is the code that i have written

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for,session
import os
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app import db
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash,check_password_hash

#from flaskr.db import get_db
#import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)


app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://support:support@rea-lnx-tdin01:5432/postgres'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def registration():
    Specialsym =['$','@','#']
    from models import name
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get('Username')
        password = request.form.get('Password')
        conf_password = request.form.get('RepeatPassword')
        error = None
        if not username:
            error = 'Username is required'
            flash(error)
        elif not password:
            error = 'Password is required'
            flash(error)
        elif len(username)< 4:
            error = "User Name should be of minimum of 4 characters"
            flash(error)
        elif len(username)> 12:
            error = "User Name should be of maximum of 8 characters"
            flash(error)
        elif len(password)< 6:
            error = "Password should be of minimum of six characters"
            flash(error)
        elif len(password) > 8:
            error = "Password should be of maximum of eight characters"
            flash(error)
        elif not any(char.isupper() for char in password):
            error = "Password should have at least upper case letter"
            flash(error)
        elif not any(char.isdigit() for char in password):
            error = "Password should have at least one digit"
            flash(error)
        elif not any(char.islower() for char in password):
            error = "Password should have at least one lower case letter"
            flash(error)
        elif not any(char in Specialsym for char in password):
            error ="Password should have at least one of the symbols $ @ # "
            flash(error)
        elif name.query.filter_by(username=username).first() is not None:
            error = 'User  is already registered'
            flash(error)
        elif password != conf_password:
            error = 'Passwords Must Match'
           # pass_1 = password
            #pass_2 = request.form.get('RepeatPassword')
            flash(error)
            #flash(pass_1)
            #flash(pass_2)
        elif error is None:
            user = name(username=username, password=generate_password_hash(password))
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            flash(" User Created successfully ")

        #return redirect(url_for('login_page'))
    return render_template('Esp_Index.html')


@app.route('/loginpage/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    return render_template('Loginpage.html')


@app.route('/Fulfilment/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def fulfil():
   return render_template('Ful_Product_Provider.html')


@app.route('/login/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login_page():
    from models import name
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('Username')
        password = request.form.get('Password')
        flash(username)
        error = None

        user = name.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if user is None:
            error = "User Name doesn't Exist or it's Invalid!!"
            flash(error)
            flash(user)
        elif not check_password_hash(user['password'], password):
            error = "Incorrect Password"
            flash(error)
        if error is None:
            session.clear()
            session['user_id'] = user['id']
            return redirect(url_for('fulfil.html'))

            #flash(error)
    return render_template('Loginpage.html')
```

Jinja code####

#### ESP_Base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% block head %}
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script >
  <!-- Custom Theme files -->
    <link href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/Styles.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <!-- //Custom Theme files -->
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">    <!-- //web font -->
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content" >{% block content %}

        {% endblock %}</div>
            <ul class="colorlib-bubbles">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.html#########

```
 {% extends "ESP_Base.html" %}
    {% block title %}Enterprise App Support Console{% endblock %}
    {% block head %}
      {{ super() }}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block body %}
    {% block content %}
     <h1>Enterprise Appsupport SignUp Portal Form</h1>
    {% with errors = get_flashed_messages() %}
         {% if errors %}
           {% for error in errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ error }}</strong>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
         {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
      <div class="main-w3layouts wrapper">
            <div class="main-agileinfo">
                <div class="agileits-top">
                    <form action="" method="POST">
                        <input  type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" value="{{request.form.get.Username}}">
                        <input  type="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" value="{{request.form.get.Email}}">
                        <input  type="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" value="{{request.form.get.Password}}">
                        <input  type="Password" name="RepeatPassword" placeholder="ConfirmPassword" value="{{request.form.get.RepeatPassword}}">
                        <input type="submit" value="SIGNUP">
                    </form>
                    <p>Don't have an Account? <a href="{{ url_for('login') }} "> Login Now!</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
    {% endblock %}
```

#### Login Page

```
{% extends "ESP_Base.html" %}
{% block title %}Enterprise App Support Console{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
  {{ super() }}
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>Enterprise Appsuppor Login</h1>
{% with errors = get_flashed_messages() %}
     {% if errors %}
       {% for error in errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ error }}</strong>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
     {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
  <div class="main-agileinfo">
      <div class="agileits-top">
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" >
                    <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password">
                    <p><input type = "submit" value = "Login"/></p>
                </form>
            </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Can you please advice what could be the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the content of `Loginpage.html` file too in the question?

Comment: Thanks Md. Nahidur Rahman , Added Loginpage.html.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `Index.html`. Use `url_for('login_page')` instead of `url_for('login')` like following.

```
<p>Don't have an Account? <a href="{{ url_for('login_page') }} "> Login Now!</a></p>
```

Comment: @ Md Nahidur Rahman Navigation is working perfectly okay, but i'm unable to login with existing user credentials.